# What does "in-ordinary to the Queen" mean?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage

I've seen phrases like "Physician-in-ordinary to the Queen". "Oculist-in-ordinary to the Queen", what does mean? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physician_to_the_Queen

Comment: Presumably the opposite of _Physician Extraordinary to the Queen_. (I’ve never heard either title before, incidentally, and “in ordinary” sounds strange and not immediately understandable to me either.)

Comment: a quick check of the dictionary = definition!

Comment: @lbf - 2(especially of a judge or bishop) exercising authority by virtue of office and not by deputation.

Comment: Some misleading and low-quality comments here.

Comment: @SvenYargs: But better than [an almost fanatical devotion to the Pope](http://montypython.50webs.com/scripts/Series_2/7.htm).     :-)    ⁠

Comment: Found same like phrase, "PUBLISHER IN ORDINARY TO HER MAJESTY"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is covered by [a different Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_ordinary#Royal_Household):

> In relation particularly to the staff of the British Royal Household, and more generally to those employed by the Crown, ["in ordinary"]  is used as a suffix showing that the appointment is to the regular staff, for example a priest or chaplain-in-ordinary, or a physician-in-ordinary, being a cleric or doctor in regular attendance.

In other words, this physician is just a regular employee of the monarch. The title's (literally) baroque wording is a result of the jumble of traditions and protocols surrounding the British monarchy. It's not something that would be used anywhere else, for example the ship's doctor on a cruise ship is unlikely to have "in ordinary" in his or her title.